# SQL server job dynamic schedule

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-job

I have a set of SQL server jobs and I want the schedule for them to be dynamic i.e. I want the next run date to come from a table.

I have tried updating  `next_run_date` in the `sysjobschedules` table and `next_scheduled_run_date` in  `sysjobactivity` table but this doesn't do anything.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use - `sp_update_schedule` to update the schedule.

```
sp_update_schedule 
    {   [ @schedule_id = ] schedule_id 
      | [ @name = ] 'schedule_name' }
    [ , [ @new_name = ] new_name ]
    [ , [ @enabled = ] enabled ]
    [ , [ @freq_type = ] freq_type ]
    [ , [ @freq_interval = ] freq_interval ] 
    [ , [ @freq_subday_type = ] freq_subday_type ] 
    [ , [ @freq_subday_interval = ] freq_subday_interval ] 
    [ , [ @freq_relative_interval = ] freq_relative_interval ] 
    [ , [ @freq_recurrence_factor = ] freq_recurrence_factor ] 
    [ , [ @active_start_date = ] active_start_date ] 
    [ , [ @active_end_date = ] active_end_date ] 
    [ , [ @active_start_time = ] active_start_time ] 
    [ , [ @active_end_time = ] active_end_time ] 
    [ , [ @owner_login_name = ] 'owner_login_name' ]
    [ , [ @automatic_post =] automatic_post ]
```

Comment: I looked at this sp but it doesn't have next run date. If I use this would it be like creating a new schedule every time i.e. changing the active start date?

Comment: Updating `next_run_date` in `sysjobschedules` will not solve question. The `sysjobschedules` table refreshes every 20 minutes. It depends on various of other fields - `freq_interval, freq_subday_type, freq_subday_interval, freq_relative_interval, freq_recurrence_factor, active_start_date, active_start_time`. So, you must reference these fields to change next run date.

Comment: Visit [this](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/plugging-gaps-sql-server-job-tracking) site for more information.