# Windows service to run based on timer values from SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, windows-services

I need to develop a windows service to fetch data from SQL Server which has a table with columns

```
   Report_date    report_time
   29-01-2016     10:00
   29-01-2016     14:00
   29-01-2016     18:00....so on
```

These `report_date` and `report_time` will change everyday they are not constant. I have provided a Windows application for my client which has a UI to change the `report_date` and `report_time` now I want to have a Windows service which will check values from the date and time columns and run at those particular times only instead of running continuously.

I have thought about task scheduling but as I have provided them with a Windows UI I don't want them to go back to task scheduling and do that.

I would appreciate if someone can guide me how to achieve this. I want to write the values to a text file and check for changes in the text file as I don't want a timer to hit SQL Server every 5 minutes or so. But I may face with permissions issue if I write to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a SQL Server job with a dynamic schedule? Find more about that here [Stackoverflow Dynamic Job schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314573/sql-server-job-dynamic-schedule)